# How do you configure the Apache server which ships Mac OS X?

Tags: apache, macos

Mac OS X ships with apache pre-installed, but the files are in non-standard locations.  This question is a place to collect information about where configuration files live, and how to tweak the apache installation to do things like serve php pages.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apache Config file is: /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Default DocumentRoot is: /Library/Webserver/Documents/

To enable PHP, at around line 114 (maybe) in the /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf file is the following line:

```
#LoadModule php5_module     libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Remove the pound sign to uncomment the line so now it looks like this:

```
LoadModule php5_module     libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Restart Apache: System Preferences -> Sharing -> Un-check "Web Sharing" and re-check it. 
**OR**

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Though this answer is old, the information is still true for OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Applies to El Capitan too (OSX 10.11)

Comment: System Preferences -> Sharing -> Web Sharing seems to be gone on OSX High Sierra

Answer (score 11):

Running

$ httpd -V

will show you lots of useful server information, including where the httpd.conf file can be found.

Answer (score 2):

To get SSI/includes (mod_include) to work I found I had to edit `/private/etc/apache2/users/myusername.conf` and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.

Then add the following in a .htaccess file in the root of your site:

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/html .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
```

Comment: This seems to be in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf` as of `10.8`.  it says "Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client... To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI): (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)"  They add the directive as `AddType text/html .shtml \ AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml`, but probably just out of being paranoid.  What I don't understand is where do I "tell apache"
 where MY particular `.shtml` IS?

Comment: @alexgray If I'm not mistaken that path is on OSX Server and the path that I gave is for OSX (desktop).

Answer (score 1):

httpd.conf is in /private/etc/apache2

Enable PHP by uncommenting line:

```
 LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Answer (score 1):

**/etc/httpd/users** contains user-specific configuration files which can be used to override the global configuration. For example, adding "**AddHandler server-parsed html**" to the **<Directory>** block in the **/etc/httpd/users/*.conf** file that corresponds to one user will enable mod_include parsing of HTML files for that particular user's **$HOME/Sites** directory, but nowhere else.